# Do I need to explicitly free the memory in managed C++?

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, memory-management

I have managed .net C++ dll, a function inside that do the following:

```
unsigned char* mBytes = new unsigned char[hSize];
```

How to release this mBytes before return?

Comment: `delete[] mBytes`?...

Comment: You're using `new` not `gcnew` so just treat it as you would in regular c++ code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For each:

- `new[]` - `delete[]` should be called
- `new` - `delete` should be called
- `malloc()` - `free()` should be called
- [`ref new` / `gcnew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8.aspx) - a memory is deallocated automatically

You should ***avoid taking care of memory management on your own as much as possible*** by:

- following [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom
- prefering objects with automatic storage duration over dynamically allocated ones
- taking advantage of *smart pointers* that will ensure that the memory is freed using the appropriate (explicitly specified) means and it will happen so on every return / exit path (even when an exception is thrown)
- etc.

In this case you used `new[]` for allocation, so you should deallocate this memory by calling:

```
delete[] mBytes;
```

Comment: so no change, I thought there is something special as the garbage collector.
Thanks

Comment: @Joseph: Even when it is C++/CLI, look at it as an extension of the language, not a different language.

Comment: @Joseph There _is_ something special as the garbage collector, but if you want to use it you need to request it by creating your objects with gcnew. This is done for compatibility reasons with C++. If you want a totally managed language, or at least managed by default, pick C#.

Comment: Missed the best option: pass the memory to a smart pointer that will call delete for you, on every exit path, even when an exception is thrown.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That is just using language's feature to ensure one of the points that are in my list already :)

Comment: Well yes you are right that *someone* should call delete [].  But not "you".  Anyone asking this question probably needs the suggestion to use smart pointers, *especially* since .NET uses exceptions so widely.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Hang on there, he said he had a managed DLL. So, everything is compiled to MSIL and run by the CLR after being JITted to native code. That's what I call, "managed." Of course, nonetheless, C and C++ code still has the same same syntax, semantics and pragmatics.

Comment: @Tom the compiler does not translate "Everything" to MSIL unless you use the /clr:pure option.

Comment: It does translate everything to MSIL, even the ::operator new[] call.  It doesn't translate new to gcnew.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `delete[]` operator.

```
delete[] mBytes;
```

Should do the work.

And `delete` for dealocating `new`

Althrough managed c++ can designate class to be collected via garbage collector, by keyword `__gc`. Eg. class definition:

```
 __gc class gc  {
  int* i;
  char* g;
  float* j;
};
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712825%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :)

Comment: so no change, I thought there is something special as the garbage collector.
Thanks

Comment: Oh! I made extra research. Apparently there's a '__gc' keyword to designate class to be collected by garbage collector. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712825%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :)

Comment: You should note that __gc and Managed extensions for C++ died with visual studio .net in 2003.  All new versions use C++/CLI instead